# Improve poor automatic tick position choices without explicitly specifying breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I find that `ggplot2` sometimes produces too few tick marks when using `scale_y_log10`. I am trying to produce plots automatically from arbitrary data, and I'm looking for a way to increase the number of tick marks without explicitly specifying them (since I don't know ahead of time what the data will be). For instance, here's a function to create a simple scatterplot with a log-y-scale:

```
example_plot <- function(x) {
  p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=MW, y=rel.Ki)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_log10()
  p
}
```

This will often work well, but with the following data

```
d <- structure(list(MW = c(89.09, 174.2, 147.13, 75.07, 131.17, 131.17, 146.19, 149.21, 165.19, 115.13, 181.19, 117.15), rel.Ki = c(2.91438577473767, 1, 1.07761254731238, 1.0475715900998, 0.960123906592881, 0.480428471483881,  1.50210548081627, 0.318457530434953, 0.458477212731015, 1.92246139937586,  0.604121577795352, 2.4111345825694)), .Names = c("MW", "rel.Ki"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 6L, 11L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 31L, 36L, 41L, 47L, 54L, 59L))
```

it produces

```
print(example_plot(d))
```

[image]

The single tick mark on the y axis is not very helpful. Is there any way I can prevent this situation, short of rewriting the automatic tick-position-picking function?

Comment: Have you tried setting the y limits to `c(1,10)` or `c(1,100)`, after you set the axes to be logarithmic?

Comment: If you don't have to use `ggplot` a standard old `with(d,plot(MW,rel.Ki,log="y"))` gives nearly the exact same results but with sensible y-axis point choices.

Comment: As I state in the post, I really can't explicitly set the limits, since I don't know what the range of the data will be - the problem is that the tick selection _sometimes_ works poorly.

Comment: @thelatemail +1 for convincing me that base graphics is good for something!

Comment: you can set the limits using `c(10^floor(log10(min(rel.Ki,na.rm=TRUE))), 10^ceiling(log10(max(rel.Ki,na.rm=TRUE))))`. This gives me c(0.1,10), as you'd expect.

Comment: @DrewSteen - I really don't understand the hate for base graphics - it is extraordinarily flexible. Sometimes a bit more typing, but it has been really well thought out most of the time.

Comment: @AndyClifton: That's a beauty. (Except it has to be `x$rel.Ki`, apparently). Why don't you post that as an answer.

Comment: (and @thelatemail: Not hate from me, really - it just seems that lots of tasks are way easier in `ggplot2`, so I haven't really bothered with base. But you're right: when flexibility is important, base gets useful.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An interesting discovery I just made by reading `?continuous_scale` is that the `breaks` argument can be:

> a function, that when called with a single argument, a character vector giving the limits of the scale, returns a character vector specifying which breaks to display.

So to guarantee a certain number of breaks, you could do something like:

```
break_setter = function(lims) {
  return(seq(from=as.numeric(lims[1]), to=as.numeric(lims[2]), length.out=5))
}

ggplot(d, aes(x=MW, y=rel.Ki)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_log10(breaks=break_setter)
```

Obviously the very simple example function is not very well adapted to the logarithmic nature of the data, but it does show how you could approach this a bit more programmatically.

---

You can also use `pretty`, which takes a suggestion for a number of breaks and returns nice round numbers. Using

```
break_setter = function(lims) {
    return(pretty(x = as.numeric(lims), n = 5))
}
```

yields the following:

[image: logbreaks]

Even better, we can make `break_setter()` return an appropriate function with whatever `n` you want and a default of, say, 5.

```
break_setter = function(n = 5) {
   function(lims) {pretty(x = as.numeric(lims), n = n)}
}

ggplot(d, aes(x=MW, y=rel.Ki)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_log10(breaks=break_setter())  ## 5 breaks as above

ggplot(d, aes(x=MW, y=rel.Ki)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_log10(breaks=break_setter(20))
```

Comment: @shujaa: No worries, it's definitely an improvement over the very basic proof of concept I had.

Comment: so here you are using the `lims` from my answer? Just wondering.

Comment: @AndyClifton: No, when you use a function as the `breaks` argument in a `continuous_scale`, it takes the automatically determined limits and feeds them through the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the limits programmatically. For example, using the data you provide, we can define the limits in the function like this:

```
example_plot <- function(x){
  # identify the range of data
  lims <- c(10^floor(log10(min(x$rel.Ki, na.rm=TRUE))), 
    10^ceiling(log10(max(x$rel.Ki, na.rm=TRUE))))
  # require ggplot2
  require('ggplot2')
  # create the plot
  p <- ggplot(data = x, aes(x = MW, y = rel.Ki)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_log10(limits = lims)
  p
}

print(example_plot(d))
```

Then you get a plot with ticks at the nearest decade:

[image: How to set limits programmatically]

Then, if you want to add a logarithmic grid, use the `breaks` option to `scale_y_log10()` as Marius et al. suggest:

```
 example_plot <- function(x){
  # identify the range of data      
  lims <- c(10^floor(log10(min(x$rel.Ki, na.rm=TRUE))), 
            10^ceiling(log10(max(x$rel.Ki, na.rm=TRUE))))  
   # require ggplot2
  require('ggplot2')
  # create the plot
  p <- ggplot(data = x, aes(x = MW, y = rel.Ki)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_log10(breaks = pretty(x = lims, n = 5),
                  limits = lims) 
  p 
}

print(example_plot(d))
```

Personally I prefer logarithmic plots to show at least an order of magnitude variation, so this approach helps ensure that happens.

[image]